# How do you insert an array of objects into the SwiftData ModelContext

Tags: swift, swift-data

You can insert one object at a time in the model context by doing this:

```swift
modelContext.insert(object)
```

If I want to insert an array of objects, I would do this:

```swift
for obj in objects {
    modelContext.insert(obj)
}
```

This works but seems ineficient. Is there a way to directly insert or append a full array of objects into the model context?

Comment: No. There is not

Comment: I think there is a workaround, like making another class that has an array of persistent models inside. However, this wrapper class can't be used with @Query.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/modelContainer(for:inMemory:isAutosaveEnabled:isUndoEnabled:onSetup:)-18hhy), the default value for `isAutosaveEnabled` is `true`.

> ["the returned context periodically checks whether it contains unsaved changes, and if so, implicitly saves those changes on your behalf"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/preserving-your-apps-model-data-across-launches)

**Consider the following optimizations:**

1. **Turn off auto-saving**: Change the `isAutosaveEnabled` to `false`.
2. **Wrap Inserts in a Single Transaction**: Use `modelContext.transaction {}` to group your insertions into a single transaction.
   This can significantly improve performance compared to multiple transactions if you're dealing with large quantity of objects.
3. **Reduce Save Frequency**: Instead of saving the context after each insertion, save it once after all insertions are complete. This reduces the overhead of writing to the disk.

**Example:**

```swift
modelContext.transaction {
    for obj in objects {
        modelContext.insert(obj)
    }
    do {
        try modelContext.save()
    } catch {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```