# iOS App Architecture : Networking vs. Saving to Core Data/SwiftData

Tags: ios, core-data, swift-data

Background: Im building an iOS Bus scheduling app. I'm getting Bus Schedule and Bus Route information from a public API. The Bus Route information is large (25000 JSON records).

Challenge: Initially I designed my app so that every time the app launches, it pulls the 25K records. But pulling and decoding that information takes 6-7 seconds every time. This seemed wasteful to me because Bus Routes change very rarely.

Approach: I tried to architect it such that Bus Route information is pulled only the first time the app is launched, and then stored into Core Data using SwiftData. For subsequent uses I would pull the info from Core Data. However, when testing I found that saving 25K objects to Core Data was taking much, much more time. It takes many minutes to do this instead of the 6-7 seconds for each API pull.

It may be in part because I have to take 25K JSON records in a decoded struct, create a @Model class with the same attributes, and then store in the modelContext one by one. I even tried improving performance by disabling autosave for each insert and wrapping it in a transaction so there's only one save triggered. (suggested here: [How do you insert an array of objects into the SwiftData ModelContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77533881/how-do-you-insert-an-array-of-objects-into-the-swiftdata-modelcontext)). None of these solutions worked for me.

```
modelContext.transaction {
    for obj in objects {
        modelContext.insert(obj)
    }
    do {
        try modelContext.save()
    } catch {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Question: Is there a way to architect the app so that I only pull the Route information once and store it? Or in this context is it preferable to just pull all 25K records at every launch even though the info rarely changes? Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Are you in control of the backend where you pull the JSON from? Then you could add some sort of timestamp to only fetch data changed since your last fetch. Then you always only get the changed objects instead of the whole dump.

Comment: If you have no relations (only one entity), you could use a BatchInsert Request, but depending on the API you use, you might improve the way for getting the data. Do you know if it changed (ie, do you need to retrieve them all), do you need to download the FULL 25k values each time? Can you split, are all of them needed?

Comment: Since your original approach was (presumably) to hold the decoded JSON in memory and (presumably) you didn't have any problem with searching this data, do you actually need Core Data?  Can you just save the JSON file locally and load it back into memory on launch?

Comment: Would it be possible to calculate a checksum on the downloaded json and compare it to the checksum of the previous download to see if it’s changed?

Comment: @Paulw11 Your suggestion worked! Thanks a lot.